# Explain clearly what is wrong with the following argument (Epsilon Delta proof of limits as $x\to\infty$)

Tags: calculus

I understand how to use the epsilon-delta proof to prove the limit as $x \rightarrow \infty$, but I do not understand what is going on for this question. It seems that they're going backwards? I have only proved limits where the limit is first given - I have never encountered something like this.

If someone could explain this to me clearly and step-by-step, I would appreciate it. Thank you.

Problem (This is NOT my solution, it is the problem I am trying to solve):

Explain clearly what is wrong with the following argument:

Let $f(x)=\frac{\sin(2x)}{20} + \frac{1}{x}$. Choose $\epsilon=0.1$ and $N=20$.
Then for $x > N \rightarrow \frac{1}{x} < \frac{1}{20}$.

Hence, since $|\sin(2x)|\leq 1$, we have $|f(x) - 0| < 1/20 + 1/20 = \epsilon \hspace{1mm}, \forall x > N$.
It follows that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x) \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Your reasoning is fine for the specific choice $\epsilon=0.1$. How would you choose $N$ for a general $\epsilon>0$?

Comment: @JohnDawkins That's not my solution, it's the actual problem.

Comment: I see now.  What is wrong with the argument presented in the problem is that it deals only with one particular $\epsilon$ (namely, $\epsilon=0.1$), whereas a correct argument would show that for each $\epsilon>0$ there is a choice of $N$ such that if $x>N$ then $|f(x)-0|<\epsilon$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Thanks but as my post specified, I'm looking for a more elaborate, step-by-step solution. Please read my full post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As John Dawkins has pointed out, the alleged proof only deals with a *particular* $\epsilon$, where what is needed is an *arbitrary* $\epsilon$. Here is the idea in more detail.

Start by recalling the definition of a limit as $x$ tends to infinity: $L$ is the limit of $f(x)$ as $x \to \infty$ iff for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $N$ such that if $x > N$, then $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$. Note that the definition requires that *all* $\epsilon$ satisfy some condition, not merely that *some* $\epsilon$ does.

Now, in light of this definition, what is wrong with the alleged proof that you've cited? Simply this: the argument establishes that there exists *some* $\epsilon$, namely $\epsilon = 1/10$, and some choice $N$ such that $x > N$ implies $|f(x) - 0| < \epsilon$. But this is not all that the definition of a limit requires. What is required is something stronger, namely that such an $N$ can be found for *any* $\epsilon >0$.

Note that a correct proof would start with something like, "Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given/arbitrary/etc," and then proceed to find an $N$ that satisfies the definition of a limit *no matter what* $\epsilon$ happens to be.

Answer (score 3):

The main issue with the argument provided in the problem is the the fact that it only verifies the condition $|f(x) - 0| < \varepsilon$ for the specific value of $\varepsilon = 0.1$.

To be able to apply the [Cauchy definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit) of the limit at infinity, the condition $|f(x) - 0| < \varepsilon$ has to be satisfied for any *arbitrarily small* positive value of $\varepsilon$. However, this condition would fail for $\varepsilon < \frac{1}{20}$.

Let us define a sequence of points as $x_n = \frac{\pi}{4} + n\pi$, where $n$ is a natural number. We have
$$ |f(x_n) - 0| = \left| \frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi\right)}{20} + \frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{4} + n\pi}\right| $$
The first term evaluates nicely to $\frac{1}{20}$, and the second term is non-negative, hence we can say that for any value of $n$
$$ |f(x_n)| \geq \frac{1}{20} $$
Therefore, we have infinitely many points for which the value of the function is greater than $\frac{1}{20}$ (we can plug in any value of $n$, arbitrarily large), so for a value of $\varepsilon$ smaller than that, it is impossible to choose the value of $N$ so that the inequality holds.

The trick I have used here is a negation of the [Heine definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Other_characterizations) of a limit. It comes particularly useful in some cases when sine or cosine functions are involved.